Cipher suite TLS 1.2 handshake error when connecting to SQL Server with sqlcmd
I'm trying to make a docker container to manipulate data from a SQL Server.
Description of the problem and devices involved
Here's the list of relevant devices:

The docker container: OS is Debian 12.
The host machine: Ubuntu 22.04.
The SQL Server: version is 2016 13.0.2026. Running on a Windows Server 2012R2 VM. And no I can't upgrade any of these (I asked...).

I'm using the exact same credentials (sourced from the same .env file to avoid errors).
I am able to connect via sqlcmd from the host (using sqlcmd v1.5.0, ODBC 17, and openssl 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.18).
I'm using this command to connect from the host:
        sqlcmd \
        --server "$UTT_SQLDB_SERVERNAME" \
        --database-name "$UTT_SQLDB_DATABASE" \
        --user-name "$UTT_SQLDB_USERNAME" \
        --password "$UTT_SQLDB_PASSWORD"

But from the docker container I can't (using sqlcmd 17.10.0001.1 Linux, ODBC 17, and openssl 3.0.14-1~deb12u2):
I'm using this command to connect from the container:
sqlcmd \
    -S "$UTT_SQLDB_SERVERNAME" \
    -U "$UTT_SQLDB_USERNAME" \
    -P "$UTT_SQLDB_PASSWORD" \
    -d "$UTT_SQLDB_DATABASE"

There is no firewall problem since I can telnet and ping the SQL Server from the container.
Error messages
On the container I get the following error message:
root@50f7a7519b2b:/var/www/html# sqlcmd -S $UTT_SQLDB_SERVERNAME -U $UTT_SQLDB_USERNAME -P $UTT_SQLDB_PASSWORD -d $UTT_SQLDB_DATABASE
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish connection.

And on the SQL Server log I get these two error messages (I translated them from French):
TLS Error Code 40: This indicates a handshake failure during the TLS negotiation. It happens when the client and server cannot agree on the encryption protocols or ciphers.

SChannel Error 1205: This is a Windows error related to SChannel (Secure Channel), which is the component responsible for handling SSL/TLS encryption. Error 1205 generally means there was a mismatch in the TLS configuration between the client and the server.

What I've tried
Since it seems to be a cipher suite problem I tried to connect directly with openssl like this (from the container):
root@50f7a7519b2b:/var/www/html# openssl s_client -connect $UTT_SQLDB_SERVERNAME:1433 -tls1_2
CONNECTED(00000003)
root@50f7a7519b2b:/var/www/html# openssl s_client -connect $UTT_SQLDB_SERVERNAME:1433 -tls1_1
CONNECTED(00000003)
root@50f7a7519b2b:/var/www/html# openssl s_client -connect $UTT_SQLDB_SERVERNAME:1433 -tls1  
CONNECTED(00000003)

And it works. Which confuses me.
I also don't understand why I'm able to connect from the host but not from the container using equivalent commands and similar OS?
I also tried running the container in host network mode. No luck.

Have you followed the documentation for enabling TLS1.2 on 2012R2? https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392 you need the latest updates as well as changing the registry settings (you can use the free IIScrypto tool for this). Note that you should probably disable TLS1 and 1.1 as well as insecure ciphers at the same time.

I believe it is enabled since I already can connect with openssl CLI -tls1_2? Also I'm afraid of breaking other old programs that use the database if I disable tls 1 and 1.1. It's a production server and many old unupated programs interact with it.

And no I can't upgrade any of these (I asked...)  You did it the wrong way.  Go through all the CVEs at https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/2016/01/sql-server-2016-versions.html that were fixed in builds later than 13.0.2026, find as many  remotely-exploitable critical ones that you can, and ask again with those vulnerabilities clearly listed along with their impacts.

Also, IME openssl s_client -connect $UTT_SQLDB_SERVERNAME:1433 -tls1 doesn't seem to always prevent OpenSSL from using TLSv1, depending on your OpenSSL version.  You might need to add -no_tls1_2 -no_tls1_1 and maybe -no_tls1_3 if your version of OpenSSL supports TLSv1.3.

openssl doesn't really prove anything because OpenSSL has its own libraries, you'd need to test with a .NET app. Like I said, you'd need to enable TLS 1.2, at the very least just check it in the registry, or we can't help you.

@AndrewHenle I wish they understood how vulnerable they are but people above me at work just don't care.

Please find the SQL 2016 Build Versions at the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/releases/sqlserver-2016/build-versions
There seems a significant gap between the version mentioned above and last CU & other updates.
Login-phase-errors logs  seems similar to the TLS handshake errors mentioned above.
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sqlclient-troubleshooting-guide?view=sql-server-2016#login-phase-errors
According to the following links you should update SQL Server
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sqlclient-troubleshooting-guide?view=sql-server-2016#possible-reasons-and-solutions
